# Why wouldn't a global object's property accept a new assignment?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign a new value to the 'notes' property of the 'attendee' object in this global session object... whenever I try the assignment though, the value doesn't keep.

From the console in webkit:

```
> session['attendee']['notes']
null
> session['attendee']['notes'] = "test"
"test"
> session['attendee']['notes']
null
> window.session['attendee']['notes'] = "test"
"test"
> session['attendee']['notes']
null
> window.session['attendee']['notes']
null
```

Session is set like so in a global scope:

```
window.session = {};
```

And then later on I'm assigning an object pulled from the browser's sql database like this;

```
window.session['attendee'] = {'name':'mike' ..etc..}
```

**Update:**

Here's some more console info:

```
> window.session['attendee']
Object
  address_1: null
  address_2: null
  app_id: 1
  badge_id: null
  budget: null
  city: null
  company: null
  decision_maker: null
  email: null
  first_name: "Anonymous"
  followup: null
  id: null
  is_influencer: null
  is_purchaser: null
  is_user: null
  last_name: ""
  notes: null
  phone: null
  rating: null
  scanned: 1
  state: null
  synced: null
  zip: null
  __proto__: Object
> window.session['attendee'].notes
null
> window.session['attendee'].notes = "TEST"
"TEST"
> window.session['attendee'].notes
null
```

So there's an object in session.attendee and "notes" is a property in that object, but assigning a value to it doesn't stick.

Comment: What is `session` and what is `session['attendee']`?

Comment: Yeah, we need to see where session and session['attendee'] are instantiated

Comment: session is instantiated like this: window.session = {};

Comment: session['attendee'] is set like this: 

session['attendee'] = user; ...where user is an object {'name':'mike' ...}

Comment: @mboyle - Just paste the pertinent code into your question please. It will greatly improve your chance of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to assign to a property of a non-object won't do anything. Ensure the order of assignment looks something like:

```
window.session = {};
window.session.attendee = {};
window.session.attendee.notes = "test";
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. I assume you're doing something silly.

```
window.session;
window.session = {};
window.session = {attendee:{notes:""}};
window.session.attendee.notes = "awesome";
session.attendee.notes; // "awesome"
```

Here's what the output looks like in the console:

```
window.session;
undefined
window.session = {};
Object
window.session = {attendee:{notes:""}};
Object
window.session.attendee.notes = "awesome";
"awesome"
window.session.attendee
Object
notes: "awesome"
__proto__: Object
```